# Not able to trigger WebAPI get method from Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

```
public class FileUploadController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSomeTypes()
    {
        try
        {
            //logic implementation
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    return Ok(listofSomeType);
}
```

In my angularJS controller, I am trying to call this using

```
var serviceResult = $http.get("/api/FileUpload/GetSomeTypes");
serviceResult.success(function (data) {
    vm.someTypes = data;
})
```

I get a http://localhost:90/api/FileUpload/GetSomeTypes 500 (Internal Server Error) on the call.
I see the error An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request: Strange, i do not find any other action method with same name, infact i renamed the method and tried

Thanks

Comment: are you getting any console error?

Comment: @BalajiM yes, i get a 500 Internal server error. Updated the question

Comment: the problem with the api controller you have called, can you share the error details,

Comment: I only see an 500 error, dont seem to find more details on the error in the browser

Comment: just click the error path link or go to network tab in console you have to get the clear log details. by using the error details shall we find the solution easily. also the problem with the webapi controller pls correct that.

Comment: Thanks. I see the error An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request: Strange, i do not find any other action method with same name, infact i renamed the method and tried.

Comment: public static void Register( HttpConfiguration config ) {     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( "DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}" );     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(         name: "DefaultApiWithID",         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",         defaults: null     ); } can you try the routeconfig like as above

Comment: @BalajiM THanks a lot. Using WebApi for the 1st time in my application. Missed the controller/action Routing, Register method only had controller/id maproute.